# Angular Translate implementation

Tags: angular, translate

Please suggest me an implementation for translation of angular app to different languages. I have used ngx-translate also. But wan to translate entire app at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular i18n translation technique

[i18n translation technique](https://angular.io/guide/i18n)

**Create minimal Angular4 project**
We use @angular/cli to create a new project named “traduction” in the terminal:

```
 ng new traduction --prefix tr
    cd traduction
    ng serve -o
```

**Install and load ngx-translate**

Use npm in your terminal within the project folder “traduction”:

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader
```

**Import the necessary modules into app.module.ts :**

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
```

Add a function, that returns a “TranslateHttpLoader” and export it (needed by AoT). In this case the HttpLoaderFactory function we create, returns a Object that can load Translations using Http and .json, but you could write your own Class that for example uses a global JavaScript variable instead of loading a file, or that uses Google Translate:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

We then need to import our modules into the @NgModule, this is the import that tells Angular to load this Module into your AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

It would have been so much easier if Angular would have used the keywords “load” or “submodule” instead of “import”, cause at the beginning it’s easy to confuse the ES2015 import with the NgModule import.

**Inject the TranslateService**

In “app.component.ts” we now init the “TranslateService”, we import the TranslateService:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

Then inside the AppComponent Class we inject the service and define our default language. And to be ready for the next step, we add a function to switch the language.

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  switchLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
  }
```

**Create .json translation files**

We now create our translation files inside the assets/i18n folder:

**src/assets/i18n/en.json**

```
{
    "Title": "Translation example",
    "Intro": "Hello I am Arthur, I am 42 years old."
}
```

**src/assets/i18n/fr.json**

```
{
    "Title": "Exemple de traduction",
    "Intro": "Bonjour je m'appelle Arthur, j'ai 42 ans."
}
```

These are simple .json files that will be loaded by our “TranslateHttpLoader” we created in “app.module.ts”.

**Translate simple title and intro**

In app.component.html we add a header with the translate “directive” inside the “h1” tag. This directive will take the text inside the tag and replace it with the matching translation. If you use the directive you have to make sure, that there is nothing else inside the tag but the text.

As a second example we use the “TranslationPipe” to translate a label with define as a inline string. As we sometimes have value inside a translation that we want to replace, we can pass a data object into the “translate” pipe.

```
<h1 translate>Title</h1>

<div>
  {{ 'Intro' | translate:user }}
</div>
```

**Integrate language switcher**

We can now attach our language switcher function that we saw above in app.component.ts to a button. In this case we create a button for each language and call the switchLanguage() function with the matching language key.

```
<button (click)="switchLanguage('en')">en</button>

<button (click)="switchLanguage('fr')">fr</button>
```

**Translate sentence with variable**

As mentioned before, you sometimes have sentences to that contain variable. In this little example we have a user object with age and name inside the “app.component.ts”, and we want to translate a sentence that will contain this values:

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  user = {
    name: 'Arthur',
    age: 42
  };
...
}
```

Because we pass this object into the “translate” pipe, we can now use it’s properties in our translation with the {{ placeholder }} notation.

**src/assets/i18n/en.json**

```
{
    "Title": "Translation example",
    "Intro": "Hello I am {{name}}, I am {{age}} years old."
}
```

**src/assets/i18n/fr.json**

```
{
    "Title": "Exemple de traduction",
    "Intro": "Bonjour je m'appelle {{name}}, j'ai {{age}} ans."
}
```

**Using nested .json objects**

If you want to be able to have more control on your translation, and for example translate page blocks (from the end-user perspective) or components (from the developer perspective), one solution could be the following; use nested .json objects as described in the git repo. An example could look like this in the -json files:

```
{
    "Title": "Translation example",
    "Intro": "Hello I am {{name}}, I am {{age}} years old.",
    "Startpage": {
        "TranslationSections": "Hello World"
    },
     "Aboutpage": {
        "TranslationSections": "We are letsboot"
    }
}

{
    "Title": "Exemple de traduction",
    "Intro": "Bonjour je m'appelle {{name}}, j'ai {{age}} ans.",
    "Startpage": {
        "TranslationSections": "Bonjour Monde"
    },
    "Aboutpage": {
        "TranslationSections": "Nous sommes letsboot"
    }
}
```

**And in the corresponding template:**

```
<h1 translate>Title</h1>

<div>
  {{ 'Intro' | translate:user }}
</div>

<div>
  {{ 'Startpage.TranslationSections' | translate }}
</div>

<div>
  {{ 'Aboutpage.TranslationSections' | translate }}
</div>

<br/>

<button (click)="switchLanguage('en')">en</button>
<button (click)="switchLanguage('fr')">fr</button>
```

Example: [angular translation](https://medium.com/letsboot/translate-angular-4-apps-with-ngx-translate-83302fb6c10d)

Comment: And what if I have 20 components? should I need to inject TranslateService in each one?

Comment: @danielgi you dont need to put translation service evrywhere follow the above steps . Only need to import in app.component

Comment: thanks, but your solution only work on .html files but no .ts files. e.g.- I can't call translate.instant()

Comment: @daniel gi you can use translation service to work in .ts files

Comment: so If I have 20 components should I need to inject the translation service in each one in order to use it in ts files ? there is no a global instace for .ts files also?

Comment: @danielgi you can import translation service in app module and use evrywhere